# Is it possible to have a sum of text REPLACE'd cells in openoffice.org calc?

Tags: microsoft-excel, openoffice, openoffice-calc

I have a spreadsheet in calc where I paste dollar values ("$2.50") from another source, but sometimes these are in CAD and appear as "C $3.75", so I would like to be able to keep those strings as they are and still be able to add them. Something like:

```
=SUM(VALUE(REPLACE(A20:A32;1;3;'')))
```

or:

```
=SUM(VALUE(RIGHT(A20:A32;LEN(A20:A32)-2)))
```

neither of which obviously work (`REPLACE` doesn't take a range). I have searched for quite a while, and can't seem to find a way to do this. My first thought was to use `SUMPRODUCT` somehow, but I don't even know how to approach this. I did find something about arrays, but that's currently beyond my scope of understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great, as it usually happens, moments after you ask publicly, you find the answer yourself. In my case, the problem was that once you enter:

```
=SUM(VALUE(RIGHT(A20:A24;LEN(A20:A24)-2)))
```

You have to press "Ctrl+Shift+Enter" instead of just "Enter" when you want to accept the formula. (It won't work in an already entered formula unless you change it first, eg: add a space, then delete the space, then press "Ctrl+Shift+Enter" to accept the changes). This causes the formula to be evaluated as an array, which can be seen in the cell formula preview where openoffice shows it as:

```
{=SUM(VALUE(RIGHT(A20:A24;LEN(A20:A24)-2)))}
```

Though when you edit it, it removes the {}'s. So there it is, just press  "Ctrl+Shift+Enter" instead of just "Enter" and that makes OpenOffice happy. Hope it helps someone out there.

---

NOTE:
It seems this only works with `RIGHT()` and not `REPLACE()` for some reason, if you know why (or how to make it work) please let me know.

This does work though:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(VALUE(REPLACE(A17:A18;1;3;'')))
```

No "Ctrl+Shift+Enter" required.